# How to attract more interest to an open Stack Overflow question

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I posted a question a few days ago and got some answers but they didn't fully fix my problem. It seems like now it's lost behind all the new questions. I thought about reposting, but I feel it's better to keep everything in the same thread. Is there a way to promote my question back to the top?

This is blatant promotion of the question, but I am genuinely interested in how to get more answers.

So here's the link in case you can help: [Hover in IE not working when hovering over full div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550259/hover-in-ie-not-working-when-hovering-over-full-div)

Comment: @JiminyCricket: Questions about StackOverflow.com itself should be posted at meta.stackoverflow.com. In a few seconds or minutes, your post will be moved there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can *edit* your question. When you do that, it will be put on the top of the StackOverflow.com front page.
- After two days, you can create a *bounty* on your question, that is, an award. When there is a bounty on your question, you can award a good answer a bit of your own reputation (up to 500, if I recall correctly). This will draw attention to your question.
- Once in a while, the Community (a bot user) will "touch" unanswered and forgotten questions. This amounts to the same thing as an edit, so the question will be shown on the front page for a while.